# print sql count result in a table with the correct order using while

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have 2 `while` loops, one inside the other.

So

```
while ($info5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5))
{

 print "</td>";
```

then I have this sql query

```
 include('database.inc');

$sql6 = "SELECT count(checkins.placeID) as methoda FROM checkins, places, activities WHERE activities.actID=places.placeActivity AND checkins.placeID = places.placeID and checkins.cityID = ".$city." group by checkins.placeID order by checkins.placeID, activityName";

$result6=mysql_query($sql6);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result6);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result6))
    {
     echo $row["methoda"];
 }
      print "</td></tr></table>" ;

        }?>
```

The problem is that I receive 1 table, for example like this:

`Place1 -> 321`

`Place2 -> 321`

`Place3 -> 321`

The order is right, but I receive it as an array!
The correct should be

`Place1 -> 3`

`Place2 -> 2`

`Place3 -> 1`

I don't know how to split the array `$row`, or if it is a transpose problem, or the count command has stacked, etc. I don't really know! Please help me.

Comment: This is the right while, sorry guys, but i am too angry.   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result6))
    {
    
    foreach($row as $cell)
       echo $cell;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be something like this:

```
include('database.inc');

echo "<table>";

//first query....

while ($info5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5))
{

    $sql6 = "SELECT count(checkins.placeID) as methoda FROM checkins, places, activities WHERE activities.actID=places.placeActivity AND checkins.placeID = places.placeID and checkins.cityID = ".$city." group by checkins.placeID order by checkins.placeID, activityName";

    $result6=mysql_query($sql6);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result6);

    echo "<tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result6))
    {
       echo "<td>".$row["methoda"]."</td>";
    }
    print "</tr>" ;

}?></table>
```

Edit it according to your requirement. Notice the placement of `td`, `tr` and `table` tags

Comment: i have already tried this and so many other ways! i think the problem is that $row is an array and somehow i take as a result the whole array. I want to split this array. The table is created fine, but i see the same result in every cell. If  i have a table with 3 rows i see in every sell of these rows the same result (321). But actually i need to take at the cell of the first row -> 3,  at the cell of the second row -> 2 and so on...